# Editing excel online and in workbook

Tags: excel

I have a vba code in my .xlsm excel file. When i edit it online, my code does not work. But it works when i have been editing it in Work book.

Why is this so?

The vba code contains a code for stoping duplicate value entry for a column in excel

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is that you can open workbooks containing macros online but you can't do anything with the code.

[Work with macros in Excel Online](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/work-with-macros-in-excel-online-98784ad0-898c-43aa-a1da-4f0fb5014343)

> Although you can't work with macros in Excel Online, you can open a
>   workbook that contains macros—though you won't be able to see the
>   macros. You can edit the worksheets and save a workbook containing
>   macros in Excel Online. The macros will remain in the workbook, and
>   you open the workbook in the Excel desktop application to view and
>   edit the macros.

Bottom line: Use Excel desktop application to work with macros.

You can vote for it as a feature here:

[Developer tab, macros, custom add-ins for online Excel](https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/274580-excel-online/suggestions/13203012-developer-tab-macros-custom-add-ins-for-online-e)