# Use userform across multiple devices

Tags: excel, vba, database, userform

I am currently running excel version 2104 and have worked hard creating a variety of userforms for my work. Everything works perfectly on my computer but I noticed that if I try accessing the excel document on excel online I lose the ability to run my userforms and get an error stating that their are unsupported features in my workbook. I was wondering if there is any work around to this or if there is an alternative way to have multiple people access this workbook so they may use the userforms I have created. Ideally I would want the users that are accessing my userforms to not have access to the database sheets I have created.

Comment: VBA/userforms are not supported in the "web" version of Excel.  Users would need to open your workbook in the client application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Editing excel online and in workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50318406/editing-excel-online-and-in-workbook)